# Rails gem Ratyrate showings stars only after refresh and not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, raty

(Saw many posts with these problems and got it working, so I will upload solution)

I'm using [Ratyrate](https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate) without Devise and the stars only appear after a web refresh and they do not save the previously assigned rate.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue with:

> 1. Specifying version in each Rating Migration (currently using ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1])
> 2. Changing Rate Controller "create" method, replacing "if user_signed_in?" with "if current_user"
> 3. Adding "post '/rate' => 'rater#create', :as => 'rate'" to routes.rb (gem should do this for you)
> 4. Adding 
>      <%= javascript_include_tag 'ratyrate.js', "data-turbolinks-track": false %> at the bottom of show.html.erb (the view of the model you want to rate)

Hope this helps !